# How to check if a string contains any 3 element from a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I check if any 3 elements from a given list are present in a string.

For example -

```py
words_to_check = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear']

sample_string = 'apple, orange, and banana are fruits'
Answer - True

sample_string = 'apple and orange are fruits'
Answer - False (since only 2 elements match)

sample_string = 'apple, banana and pear are fruits'
Answer - True


sample_string = 'apple is a fruit'
Answer - False
```

I know I can do the following if I want to check if the string contains any 1 element from the list -

```py
if any(fruit in sample_string for fruit in words_to_check):
    print(sample_string)
```

How can I do the same for any 3 (or n) elements?

I know I can do this using 3 if conditions but is there any elegant/pythonic way to solve this?

Comment: Count how many time `fruit in sample_string` is `True`.

Comment: I'd think about potentially splitting the `sample_string` into a list and then pop-ing values when they match

Comment: What is the correct number of matches for `grapple` or `appear` - should they count because `apple` and `pear` are substrings, or not because they aren't the words `apple` and `pear`?

Comment: @kaya3 They won't count as they aren't the exact words. I am looking for word match. Selcuk's answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Selcuk's answer will match `grapple` and `appear`, though.

Comment: @kaya3 Yeah, you're right, my bad. They'll match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
>>> sample_string = 'apple, orange, and banana are fruits'
>>> len([True for fruit in words_to_check if fruit in sample_string])
3
```

Comment: You may as well do this: `sum(fruit in sample_string for fruit in words_to_check)`

Comment: @Julien True, but explicit is better than implicit. Boolean addition is a bit obfuscated.

Comment: I would write `sum(1 for fruit in words_to_check if fruit in sample_string)`, following the `sum(1 for ...)` idiom for counting things. Using `len`, it might be more natural to write `len([fruit for ...])` simply because it makes clear the intention that you're counting fruits.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a regex and sets: first find all matches of `\w+` (i.e. one or more word-characters), form a set of the results, and take the size of the intersection of that set with your words-to-check. Note that I've made `words_to_check` a set for this purpose.

```py
>>> words_to_check = {'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear'}
>>> sample_string = 'apple, orange, and banana are fruits'
>>> import re
>>> all_words = set(re.findall(r'\w+', sample_string))
>>> len(all_words & words_to_check)
3
```

Step-by-step:

- `re.findall` returns the list `['apple', 'orange', 'and', 'banana', 'are', 'fruits']`
- So `all_words` is the set `{'apple', 'orange', 'and', 'banana', 'are', 'fruits'}`
- So `all_words & words_to_check` is the set `{'banana', 'orange', 'apple'}`
- So its size is `3`.

This solution is a bit less neat compared to the solutions using list comprehensions, but it has the advantage of running in O(*m* + *n*) time where *m* is the number of words to check, and *n* is the length of the sample string. Testing `x in sample_string for x in words_to_check` takes O(*mn*) time, in comparison.

Another difference is that this won't match words like `grapple` or `appear`, where the words in `words_to_check` are substrings of words in the sample string, but don't appear as words themselves. It's not clear from your question which behaviour is better.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex and check the length:

```
import re
len(re.compile('|'.join(words_to_check),re.IGNORECASE).findall(sample_string))

# 3
```

Here's a function:

```
def findmatches(sample_string, words_to_check, length):
   if len(re.compile('|'.join(words_to_check),re.IGNORECASE).findall(sample_string)) == length:
     return True
   else:
     return False

sample_string = 'apple, orange, and banana are fruits'
findmatches(sample_string, words_to_check, 3)
# True

sample_string = 'apple and orange are fruits' 
findmatches(sample_string, words_to_check, 3)
# False

sample_string = 'apple, banana and pear are fruits' 
findmatches(sample_string, words_to_check, 3)
# True

sample_string = 'apple is a fruit'
findmatches(sample_string, words_to_check, 3)
# False
```